# FbId bigint with Model and Eloquent

Tags: laravel, facebook

I have created project with facebook authentication , so the user id in the project is **fbid** and the length is 17
this mean data type **bigint**.

First I'm using OS Ubuntu ,  my team using Win 10
and we use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar for debugging
in Ubuntu every thing Ok, But Windows not working properly
when I use the **Eloqunt** to get the data I facing 3 issues

- some time **fbid** revert as int Max "2147483647"
- when I use **join** or **hasMay** the query execute properly but can't merge it *( i see in debugger 2 queries for user and posts)*
- for fbid 10153262671266093 it is convert to 10153262671266092

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after time of searching i got idea to cast the fbid as string and it is work now i want to share it and discuss about this issue

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/fbid-bigint-with-model-and-eloquent